# Calling / faking a "Workbook_Open" event in VBA in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a VBA project that it would be useful to be able to restart as though it had just been opened. However, I don't want to actually restart the workbook. I have tried to close then reopen the file to trigger the "Workbook_Open" event but Excel keeps randomly opening the project in a new instance.

So I'm wondering if it is possible for me to call/fake the Workbook_Open event?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you just move whatever code you have in the Workbook_Open event to it's own module and call the code from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the event is private, `ThisWorkbook.Workbook_Open` will run the `Workbook_Open` event.

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the `Workbook_Open` event-handler directly.  It will not in any sense "re-open" the workbook, but as event-handlers are just subroutines, you can of course call them like any other subroutine.

However, this is somewhat "tricky" and ill-advised because later programmers may add things that should be done at  Workbook_Open but that have nothing to do with your specific need so, as @sous2817 noted in the comments, a *better* way to do this is to move the `Workbook_Open` code to its own subroutine and then have both your code and `Workbook_Open` call it there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these event handlers, if declared public, are ordinary subs.  You should be able to call them from your main module with Worksheet("Name").Workbook_Open.  If that failed for some reason (I cannot fathom), just empty Workbook_Open into public sub myCoolBeans() and call myCoolBeans() from Workbook_Open and where-ever.

Comment: Since it's a *workbook* event, `Worksheet("Name").Workbook_Open` doesn't make a lot of sense, right?